# Xamarin List View Item Text in horizontal and vertical middle not working

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, centering

So I have a ListView and I cant get the Text to be in both horizontal and vertical middle.

I tried this:

```
                    <ListView x:Name="EssenListView" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding EssenAnTag}"
                    Footer=""
                    SeparatorVisibility="None"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HasUnevenRows="true"
                    RefreshCommand="{Binding EssenLadenCommand}"
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                    IsRefreshing="{Binding Laedt, Mode=OneWay}"
                    ItemSelected="EssenGewaehlt">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="65" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Ausgabe}" 
                                                FontSize="18"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Label HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

As you can see in the image below if the text is small its at least horizontal centered but if the text is long and breaks its not centered at all.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" property in your Label control, like this:

```
                                  <Label Text="{Binding Ausgabe}" 
                                            FontSize="18"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"` to align text in Label.

`HorizontalOptions="Center"` align the Label itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use HasUnevenRows="True" in the Listview